# How can I stream a file/video from webclient using springboot webflux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I was using spring rest template for streaming a video from another API but I was downloading the full file and then serving it with byte ranges in a react app.

Now I need to improve this solution to support bigger files without loading the content from the API fully into memory.

I leaned how to serve a video from a local file and how to download it from external API's without loading it into the memory but I can't figure how to connect both things.

```
@GetMapping(value = ["/work/{photo_id}"])
fun getVideo(@PathVariable("photo_id") photoId: String): Mono<Resource> {
    return Mono.fromCallable { companyService.findRequestCompany() }
        .flatMap {
            webClient
                .get()
                .uri("random_url")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)
        }
}
```

How can I convert this Flux of DataBuffer into a byte range response for the frontend?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updated the question to focus only on video streaming. Do you know what could be changed in my solution to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had been asked a year ago but I hope below solution may help others,

**Controller** :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/videos")
public class VideoStreamController {

    private final VideoStreamService videoStreamService;

    public VideoStreamController(VideoStreamService videoStreamService) {
        this.videoStreamService = videoStreamService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/stream/{fileType}/{fileName}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> streamVideo(ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, @RequestHeader(value = "Range", required = false) String httpRangeList,
                                                    @PathVariable("fileType") String fileType,
                                                    @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
        return Mono.just(videoStreamService.prepareContent(fileName, fileType, httpRangeList));
    }
}
```

**Service** :

```
@Service
public class VideoStreamService {


    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VideoStreamService.class);

    /**
     * Prepare the content.
     *
     * @param fileName String.
     * @param fileType String.
     * @param range    String.
     * @return ResponseEntity.
     */
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> prepareContent(final String fileName, final String fileType, final String range) {

        try {
            final String fileKey = fileName + "." + fileType;
            long rangeStart = 0;
            long rangeEnd = CHUNK_SIZE;
            final Long fileSize = getFileSize(fileKey);
            if (range == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, VIDEO_CONTENT + fileType)
                        .header(ACCEPT_RANGES, BYTES)
                        .header(CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(rangeEnd))
                        .header(CONTENT_RANGE, BYTES + " " + rangeStart + "-" + rangeEnd + "/" + fileSize)
                        .header(CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(fileSize))
                        .body(readByteRangeNew(fileKey, rangeStart, rangeEnd)); // Read the object and convert it as bytes
            }
            String[] ranges = range.split("-");
            rangeStart = Long.parseLong(ranges[0].substring(6));
            if (ranges.length > 1) {
                rangeEnd = Long.parseLong(ranges[1]);
            } else {
                rangeEnd = rangeStart + CHUNK_SIZE;
            }

            rangeEnd = Math.min(rangeEnd, fileSize - 1);
            final byte[] data = readByteRangeNew(fileKey, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
            final String contentLength = String.valueOf((rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 1);
            HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT;
            if (rangeEnd >= fileSize) {
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus)
                    .header(CONTENT_TYPE, VIDEO_CONTENT + fileType)
                    .header(ACCEPT_RANGES, BYTES)
                    .header(CONTENT_LENGTH, contentLength)
                    .header(CONTENT_RANGE, BYTES + " " + rangeStart + "-" + rangeEnd + "/" + fileSize)
                    .body(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception while reading the file {}", e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }


    }

    /**
     * ready file byte by byte.
     *
     * @param filename String.
     * @param start    long.
     * @param end      long.
     * @return byte array.
     * @throws IOException exception.
     */
    public byte[] readByteRangeNew(String filename, long start, long end) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(getFilePath(), filename);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        byte[] result = new byte[(int) (end - start) + 1];
        System.arraycopy(data, (int) start, result, 0, (int) (end - start) + 1);
        return result;
    }


    

    /**
     * Get the filePath.
     *
     * @return String.
     */
    private String getFilePath() {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(VIDEO);
        assert url != null;
        return new File(url.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * Content length.
     *
     * @param fileName String.
     * @return Long.
     */
    public Long getFileSize(String fileName) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(fileName)
                .map(file -> Paths.get(getFilePath(), file))
                .map(this::sizeFromFile)
                .orElse(0L);
    }

    /**
     * Getting the size from the path.
     *
     * @param path Path.
     * @return Long.
     */
    private Long sizeFromFile(Path path) {
        try {
            return Files.size(path);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            logger.error("Error while getting the file size", ioException);
        }
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

**Constants** :

```
public class ApplicationConstants {
    public static final String VIDEO = "/video";

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
    public static final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
    public static final String VIDEO_CONTENT = "video/";
    public static final String CONTENT_RANGE = "Content-Range";
    public static final String ACCEPT_RANGES = "Accept-Ranges";
    public static final String BYTES = "bytes";
    public static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 314700; // modify as per the requirement

    private ApplicationConstants() {
    }
}
```

We have the video in the resource folder, But if you uploading the video to some specific folder you can use ResouceLoader interface to load the file from that specific folder that may fulfill your requirement.